# Multiple reference in one reference using achemso package

Tags: bibliographies, achemso

I would like to create references like this:[image]

I tried to use `\cite` command in a `\bibnote` but I got errors during compilation.

Here is a shortened version of my code:

```
\documentclass[journal=jacsat,manuscript=communication]{achemso}

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}       
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{notes2bib}
\begin{document}

Over the last decades, the fields of systems chemistry\bibnote{For recent reviews, see: (a)\cite{ISI:000349468200007}, (b) \cite{ISI:000329586000007}, \cite{ISI:000252411700008}}, ......

\bibliography{savedrecs}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

oh ok find it myself.
mciteplus package solves the issue.

But I couldn't find how to add the comment in the reference such as "for recent reviews, see:"